# Change file information based on another file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I have two simple text files:

The first, the reference file, looks like this -the first letter of every row is the important one.

```
G A
C A
G A
```

The second one looks like this:

```
G G G G
A A A A
A A A G
```

The second file is the one I want to change based on the information of the first.

For example, if the first two columns contain the letter G, that is `G G`, because this letter was the first letter on my reference file, I want to convert the two columns to a single column with the number `2` (indicating there were two Gs). The third and fourth columns, also have two `G`, so I want to convert these two columns also to a single columns with the number `2`.

In the last row of the second file, the first two columns have the letters `A` and `A`, but because the first letter of the last row of my reference file was a `G` I want to convert these two columns to the number 0 (indicating there were zero `G` - the first letter of the reference file is the one I am counting). The third and fourth columns have an `A` and a `G`, because there is one `G`, I want two convert this two columns to a single column with the number 1.

The converted file should look like this:

```
2 2
0 0 
0 1
```

Any help would be appreciated. Handling two files at a time and doing such conversions is not within my programming skills.

**NOTE: My real file contain the letters A,C,G and T**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the first file is called `ref` and the second file called `data`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$1; next} {print (a[FNR]==$1)+(a[FNR]==$2), (a[FNR]==$3)+(a[FNR]==$4)}' ref data
2 2
0 0
0 1
```

Explanation:

- `NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$1; next}`

  `NR` is the number of lines that have been read in so far and `FNR` is the number of lines that have been read in so far from the current file.  So, when `NR==FNR`, we know that `awk` is still processing the first file.  In that case, we save the first letter on the line in the array `a`.  The `next` statement tells `awk` to skip the rest of the commands and go on to the next line.
- `print (a[FNR]==$1)+(a[FNR]==$2), (a[FNR]==$3)+(a[FNR]==$4)`

  Because of the `next` command above, this command is only executed if we are processing the second file.  If so, we print out how many letters in the first two columns match the first letter on the corresponding row in the `ref` file, and then do the same for the third and fourth columns.

#### Handling missing data

Suppose that missing data is indicated by `0 0`.  As an example, take this data file:

```
$ cat data2
G G G G
0 0 C A
A G 0 0
```

The following awk script has been extended to show "?" where the data is missing:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$1; next} {print ($1==0)?"?":(a[FNR]==$1)+(a[FNR]==$2), ($3==0)?"?":(a[FNR]==$3)+(a[FNR]==$4)}' ref data2
2 2
? 1
1 ?
```

(The same `ref` file was used as before.)

#### Handling an arbitrary number of columns

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$1; next} {s="";for (i=1;i<NF;i=i+2) {s=s OFS (($i==0)?"?":((a[FNR]==$i)+(a[FNR]==$(i+1))))}; print s}' ref3 data3
```

Comment: I just found some columns with zeros, that is missing data on my `data` file. Is it possible to put a `?` sign whenever awk finds zeros in the columns?

Comment: @user3047092 Yes, but show me an example of that input.  When that happens, are all the columns zero?  Or is it possible that columns 1 and 2 will be zero while 3 and 4 have data, etc?

Comment: For example I added a row to the ref file: `T` and `G` and also to the data file: `0 0 T G`. When I run the awk script I get `0` and `1`. But instead of a zero I would like to get a `?` sign meaning missing data, and a `1` which is the correct number based on my ref file. Thank you.

Comment: I get this error using the new script: awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$1; next} {print >>>  $1== <<<

Comment: @user3047092 I just copied and pasted from the answer and it works for me (using Linux).  Are you on a Mac?  Also, I just updated the line to add some parens which might help for non-GNU awk.  If that doesn't fix it, I would need to see the complete formatted error message which would show the character at which your awk had a problem.

Comment: Yes I am on a Mac, but it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: I just found some files that had more than 4 columns, some have more than 10k columns. Is it possible to include all columns? Thank you again.